# Accepting a string and a string array as parameters in Typescript

Tags: arrays, string, typescript

I am trying to figure out the best way to go about this. I am converting a library to typescript and am running into one particular issue which I've had before. There is a function who's definition looks a bit like this

```
public execute(path: string | string[]): Promise<Object> {
  if (typeof path == "string") {
    // Turn the string into an array
  }
}
```

The problem is I can't convert the path parameter into an array because it is of the type `(string | string[])`. Also trying to do this fails.

```
public execute(path: string | string[]): Promise<Object> {
  newPath: string[];
  if (typeof path == "string") {
    newPath = [path];
  } else {
    newPath = path;
  }
}
```

Because path is of the type `(string | string[])` and cannot be assigned to type `string[]`. Any solutions?

Comment: `path: any` - then do the checking?

Comment: @tymeJV `any` feels dirty and doesn't offer any help when it comes to type hinting

Answer (score 2):

I actually just figured it out. Pretty simple solution if you use Typescripts built in typecasting.

```
public execute(path: string | string[]): Promise<Object> {
  if (typeof path == "string") {
    path = <string[]>[path];
  }
}
```

And boom! No errors

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do this without using type assertions (casting), using [type guards](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#typeof-type-guards):

```
public execute(path: string | string[]): Promise<Object> {
  let newPath: string[];
  if (typeof path === "string") {
    newPath = [path];
  } else {
    newPath = path;
  }
}
```

In this example, TypeScript narrows the type of `path` from `string | string[]` to just `string` inside the if block, so you don't need a type assertion.